# Редактор содержимого сайта для drupal

Tags: drupal, cms

Установил на свой сайт модуль Wysiwyg. Пытаюсь найти нормальный для него плагин. Установил и заработали только nicedit и wymeditor. По поводу ckeditor'a в настройках друпала пишет что нельзя его ставить.

Хочу поставить плагин TinyMCE,поскольку установленные не устраивают, но не ставится. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его настроить, название папок менял,бесполезно. У меня версия drupal 7.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKeditor версии 4 и выше не работает с модулем Wysiwyg, для использования Ckeditor версии 4 и выше нужно ставить модуль CKeditor. Для использования CKeditor с модулем Wysiwyg, нужно использовать библиотеку CKeditor версии 3. Все версии можно скачать с сайта [библиотеки](http://ckeditor.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Я использую ckeditor. Проблем с ним нет.

Comment: Почему то именно в настройках Wysiwyg'a написано что не надо его ставить

Comment: Я не знаю где вы нашли такую информацию, но в официальной документации написано:   

>> Wysiwyg module does not do anything useful until there is at least one editor library, such as TinyMCE, FCKeditor, or NicEdit. These need to be downloaded from third-party web sites and put into the Wysiwyg module folder.  admin/settings/wysiwyg/profile provides a list of compatible third-party editor libraries along with links to their respective websites and download pages, as well as detailed on-screen installation instructions.

Comment: Какая у вас версия друпала?

Comment: >> Какая у вас версия друпала?

Указано же: 

>> У меня версия drupal 7.22.